# How to pass 'request.POST' from views to a function in Django

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-views, view

Question Solved, code reflects the solution

For sort of a webshop (it's a bit more complicated, but helps for the idea) I have created four different forms based on the same model. 
Depending on the product I'd like to display some fields and hide others and set required if necesarry.
Note: it are not multiple forms in one view, I'd like to display only one of the four forms

in views I have the following code:

```
def add_regelset(request, bon_id, product_id):
    bon = get_object_or_404(Bon, pk=bon_id)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_choice(product, None, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            formregelset = form.save(commit=False)
            formregelset.bon_id = bon.id
            formregelset.save()
            # Haal de nieuwe regelset op en maak de nodige regels aan
            regelset = get_object_or_404(Regelset, id=formregelset.id)
            maak_regelset.delay(regelset.id)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('calculator:bondetails', args=(regelset.bon.id,)))
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = form_choice(product, False, False)

    context_dict = {'form': form, 'bon': bon, 'product': product}

    return render(request, 'calculator/regelset/regelset_add.html', context_dict)


def alter_regelset(request, regelset_id):
    regelset = get_object_or_404(Regelset, pk=regelset_id)
    product = regelset.product
    bon = get_object_or_404(Bon, pk=regelset.bon_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_choice(product, regelset, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            wijziging_regelset.delay(regelset.id)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('calculator:bondetails', args=(bon.id,)))

        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = form_choice(product, regelset, False)

    context_dict = {'form': form, 'regelset': regelset}
    return render(request, 'calculator/regelset/regelset_wijzig.html', context_dict)
```

Explanation:
Regelset = the model which links to the forms

form_choice:

```
def form_choice(product, instance, postdata):
    toepassing = product.toepassing
    afmeting = toepassing.afmeting_verplicht()

    # bepaal initial
    initial = None
    if not instance:
        instance = None
    if instance is None:
        initial = {'type_korting': MenusGlobals.KORT_PROC,
                                         'toepassing': toepassing,
                                         'product': product,
                                         'omslag_dubbelzijdig': product.omslag_dubbelzijdig,
                                         'binnenwerk_dubbelzijdig': product.binnenwerk_dubbelzijdig,
                                         'naam': product.naam,
                                         'originelen': product.get_originelen(),
                                         'oplage': product.get_oplage()}

        if toepassing.form_select == MenusGlobals.XL_PRINT:
            if afmeting:
                initial.update({'breedte_in_cm': product.get_breedte_in_cm(),
                                'hoogte_in_cm': product.get_hoogte_in_cm()})

        elif toepassing.form_select == MenusGlobals.REPRO:
            initial.update({'omslag_dubbelzijdig': product.omslag_dubbelzijdig,
                            'binnenwerk_dubbelzijdig': product.binnenwerk_dubbelzijdig,
                            'breedte_in_cm': product.get_breedte_in_cm(),
                            'hoogte_in_cm': product.get_hoogte_in_cm(),
                            'breedte_in_cm2': product.get_breedte_in_cm2(),
                            'hoogte_in_cm2': product.get_hoogte_in_cm2()})

    # bepaal form
    form = RegelsetDataFormXLprintZonderAfmeting(initial=initial, instance=instance)
    if postdata:
        form = RegelsetDataFormXLprintZonderAfmeting(postdata, initial=initial, instance=instance)

    if toepassing.form_select == MenusGlobals.XL_PRINT:
        if afmeting:
            form = RegelsetDataXLprint(initial=initial, instance=instance)

    elif toepassing.form_select == MenusGlobals.REPRO:
        alleenbinnenwerk = False
        alleenomslag = False
        for r in toepassing.toepassingsregel_set.all():
            if r.artikelgroep.repro_omslag:
                alleenomslag = True
            if r.artikelgroep.repro_binnenwerk:
                alleenbinnenwerk = True

        if alleenbinnenwerk and alleenomslag:
            form = RegelsetDataReproBinnenwerkOmslag(initial=initial, instance=instance)
        elif alleenbinnenwerk:
            form = RegelsetDataReproBinnenwerk(initial=initial, instance=instance)
        elif alleenomslag:
            form = RegelsetDataReproOmslag(initial=initial, instance=instance)

    return form
```

So far so good... Now the problem. I'd like to use the same form_choice function to define the form variable when `request.method` is `"POST"`.

What I've tried so far is to set request.POST as `kwarg`  and a `arg` in in the `form_choice` function, like this

```
form = form_choice(product, request=request)
```

and use the request argument to return the right form, but it results in a `SyntaxError`, and I don't know why.

Can anyone help me?

Updated code: to reflect solution

Comment: Can you add the `form_choice` method?

Comment: where is form_choice code? and please post full traceback

Comment: I've found the solution. I was using *args and **kwargs what results in the original data being placed in a tuple or a dictionary.

Sorry for the trouble. I'll edit the post to reflect the solution including the form-choice method

Comment: @Sjoerd It's better to post the answer as an actual answer than to edit it into the question itself. This way you can accept your own answer, and people will see that the problem is solved in the question overview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I was using *args and **kwargs to pass request.POST what results in the original data being placed in a tuple or a dictionary.

Sorry for the trouble. I'll edit the post to reflect the solution including the form-choice method